# PHP Time variable not working in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, variables, time, while-loop

I am getting time from my database, when I echo it out it works, but it doesn't work in the while loop.
However, the other variables work...

Code:

```
$resultevent = mysql_query('SELECT  venue, date, TIME_FORMAT(startTime, "%h:%i %p") AS startTime2, TIME_FORMAT(endTime, "%h:%i %p") AS endTime2 FROM events"');
$rowevent = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultevent);

$date = new DateTime($originaldate);
$newdate = $date->format('m/d/Y');
$startTime2 = $rowevent['startTime'];
$endTime2 = $rowevent['endTime'];
$venue = $rowevent['venue'];

echo $startTime2; <============== WORKS HERE

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { //the code for these queries is not shown
   echo 'getting here'; <======= WORKS
   echo $venue; <======= WORKS
   echo $startTime2; <======= DOESNT WORK
}
```

Comment: there's no variable called `$result` for starters?

Comment: Are you sure this code is exactly as you have it? And that the lines you say "work" are indeed where you think they are? I would recommend modifying your `echo` statements to look more like this: `"At line 10, we echo $startTime2 as " . $startTime2;` - this makes it unambiguous which lines are doing what.

Comment: change echo $startTime2; to echo "-".$startTime2."-"; so you can make sure that the start time variable isn't being printed out. Maybe it's null. If it is null then "--" will be printed out.

Comment: in the comment i wrote that i didn't show some of the code that deals with the while statement

Comment: it is null, but idk how, before the while loop it is not null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is returning your time columns with an alias. To read them from your row you should use the alias as an index:

```
$startTime2 = $rowevent['startTime2'];
$endTime2 = $rowevent['endTime2'];
```

Comment: Good observation. Why do you think that `echo $startTime2;` works outside of the `while` loop though? That's what was bothering me...

Comment: I don't know. Your code is incomplete, so maybe it's left over from something else.

Comment: Yeah, idk why it works from outside the while loop. Nevertheless, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1.In your loop where does `$results` came from??
2.You set startTime as startTime2 in your query same as endTime to endTime2.
and obviously it will not work even your `echo $venue`.. because you fetch nothing.

it should be like this code:

```
    $date = new DateTime($originaldate);
    $resultevent = mysql_query('SELECT  venue, date, TIME_FORMAT(startTime, "%h:%i %p") AS startTime2, TIME_FORMAT(endTime, "%h:%i %p") AS endTime2 FROM events"');

    while ($rowevent = mysql_fetch_assoc($resultevent)) { //now you fetch your query in $resultevent

       $newdate = $date->format('m/d/Y');
       $startTime2 = $rowevent['startTime2'];
       $endTime2 = $rowevent['endTime2'];
       $venue = $rowevent['venue'];

       echo 'getting here';
       echo $venue; 
       echo $startTime2;
    }
```